# PHP Breadcrumb Function using foreach loops and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am attempting to write a PHP Breadcrumb function, that uses the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] function of PHP to access an array that contains the URI.

I am currently struggle to write the function to loop through the arrays to build the final product, that is the breadcumb its self, correctly formatted.

So if we have the following call to the function:

createBreadcrumb("manage_account.php");

That is the function along with the URI as a parameter, which is what the function should use to build the breadcrumb.

So if the parameter is manage_account.php, the first array should be accessed, which is $breadcrumbArray[0][1][0];, the subsequent, $breadcrumbArray[0][1][1] relates to $breadcrumbArray[1][1]; which is the human readable version of the URI. $breadcrumbArray[2][1] is the path to the human readable version.

My arrays are as follows:

```
$this->breadcrumbArray[0] = array(
    array("index.php", 1),
    array("manage_account.php", 1, 2),
    array("manage_users.php", 1, 3),
    array("view_users.php", 1, 4),
    array("new_user.php", 1, 5),
    array("edit_user.php", 1, 6),
    array("view_user.php", 1, 7),
    array("new_module.php", 1, 8),
    array("edit_module.php", 1, 9),
    array("view_module.php", 1, 10),
    array("new_handbook.php", 1, 11),
    array("edit_handbook.php", 1, 12),
    array("view_handbook", 1, 13)
  );

$this->breadcrumbArray[1] = array(
    "1" => "Home",
    "2" => "Manage Account",
    "3" => "Manage Users",
    "4" => "View Users",
    "5" => "New Users",
    "6" => "Edit Users",
    "7" => "View User",
    "8" => "New Module",
    "9" => "Edit Module",
    "10" => "View Module",
    "11" => "New Handbook",
    "12" => "Edit Handbook",
    "13" => "View Handbook"
  );

$this->breadcrumbArray[2] = array(
    "1" => "index.php",
    "2" => "manage_account.php",
    "3" => "manage_users.php",
    "4" => "view_users.php",
    "5" => "new_user.php",
    "6" => "edit_user.php",
    "7" => "view_user.php",
    "8" => "new_module.php",
    "9" => "edit_module.php",
    "10" => "view_module.php",
    "11" => "new_handbook.php",
    "12" => "edit_handbook.php",
    "13" => "view_handbook.php"
  );
```

---

## Update

I have written the following code but I am getting an error that I do not understand.

Error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: breadcrumbArray in *** on line 90
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in *** on line 90
```

Code:

```
public function createBreadcrumb($url) {
  echo $this->breadcrumbArray[0][0][0];

  $retval;

  for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    echo $this->breadcrumbArray[0][0][0];
    if($this->$breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0] = $url) {
      echo $this->$breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0].'<br/>';
      for($x = 1; $x < 100; $x++) {

        echo '<a href="'.$this->$breadcrumbArray[2][$x].'">'.$this->$breadcrumbArray[1][$i].'</a>';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The above error was caused by not accessing the arrays correctly,

It was $this->$breadcrumbArray

It should have been $this->breadcrumbArray

---

## Update 2 (Working Code)

```
public function createBreadcrumb($url) {

  for($i = 0; $i < (count($this->breadcrumbArray[0]) - 1); $i++) {
    if($this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0] == $url) {
      for($x = 1; $x < count($this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i]); $x++) {
        if((count($this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i]) - 1) == $x) {
          echo $this->breadcrumbArray[1][$this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][$x]];
        } else {
          echo '<a href="'.$this->breadcrumbArray[2][$this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][$x]].'">'.$this->breadcrumbArray[1][$this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][$x]].'</a> > ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The above code is far from the most elegant thing I have ever written but it does give a better idea as to what I was trying to achieve as it does actually function. Any further advice is of course still very much welcome.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you! :D

Comment: I don't see a question here, just a statement of what you're building. What do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry, just realised that myself as I was reading it, I have updated the original question. Thank you Ray.

Comment: I'd recommend you add to your Post the code with function you've tried to build and someone can help you if they see an issue with it.    'Write code for me request' are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise, thank you Ray, I have updated the question.

Comment: The code you show doesn't have 90 lines like the error message indicates. So which line does the error message reference?

Comment: First, you need to tell us which is line 90. Second, instead of hardcoding the indexes of `$breadcrumbArray` just use [].

Comment: I fixed the error with line 90 and referenced it above. I'm not sure what you mean @Elin about hardcoding, can you see the new code above that is functioning?

Answer (score 0):

your question is totally unclear . As I guess you are trying to do this -

```
foreach($this->breadcumbArray[0] as $val){

    $val[2]= isset($val[2])? $val[2] : $val[1] ;
    $output[] = '<a href="'.$val[0].'">'.$this->breadcumbArray[$val[1]][$val[2]].'</a>';
}
```

Edit : You have solved your problem yourself :Y...
this `for($i = 0; $i < (count($this->breadcrumbArray[0]) - 1); $i++)` should be `for($i = 0; $i < count($this->breadcrumbArray[0]); $i++)` and it would better if write `if(isset($this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0]) && $this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0] == $url)`

Comment: That is sort of what I am attempting to do, I have rewritten the question somewhat, I am struggling to explain it, if it is still unclear, please let me know and I will continue to attempt to get my ideas on paper, thank you for your help Atiqur.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
More important:
`$this->$breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0]`

You need to change that to
`$this->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0]`

and define `$url` before using it.

Also you are going to want to check if `$myarray->breadcrumbArray[0][$i][0])` exists and break out of the loop when it doesn't.